# Form button load PowerShell script from another file

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I was thinking if this is possible:

I got a PS-Form with several buttons and whether or not you can bind the buttons to other PS files?

Example:

The main form has 3 buttons and one of the buttons is called "Create Ad User".

When I click on the button goes to Ad-Form.Ps, gets the content and generates the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that. Just a bit of exploration is required. Below is an example code

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.VisualBasic")
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$Form = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.form

$Button = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button.Name = 'Button1'
$Button.Size = "50,10"
$Button.Add_Click({
    #start content for second script
    $Form1 = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.form
    $Form1.BackColor = 'magenta'
    $Form1.ShowDialog()
    $Form1.Dispose()
    #finish content for second script
})

$Form.Controls.Add($Button)

$Form.ShowDialog()
$Form.Dispose()
```

Update:

Just add the content between the comments to a ps1 file and call inside `Add_Click` method.

```
$Button.Add_Click({
     c:\SecondForm.ps1
})
```

Comment: thank you, this is the way i do it now, but hmm i want seperate powershell files so that the script does not get that hugh.

Comment: Just add the content between the comments to a ps1 file and call inside Add_Click method.

Comment: Yes this is the way that i want do create forms, thx for the help!

Answer (score 0):

you can use a button than you have other files

```
button.add_click({    
function button{
      & '\\server\share\powershellfile.ps1'
}
```